# Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string in vue express app

Tags: vue.js, sqlite, express

Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string
Getting this error while trying to use vue-google-charts to implement line graph in vue express web app with sqlite db and have no clue what is wrong. The web app deploys and the error is showing in my localhost browser. Have tried looking at other solutions to no avail.

Here is the code for the component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <v-row>
        <v-col
        cols="12">
            <GChart
                type="LineChart"
                :data="chartData"
                :options="chartOptions"
                :colors="colors"
            />
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import GetUsages from '@/services/GetUsages'
import GetService from '@/services/GetService'
import { GChart } from 'vue-google-charts'

export default {
    components: {
       GChart
   },
data () {
    return {
        print: null,
        selectedGradient: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
        chartData: null,
        chartOptions: {
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Seconds'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Gallons'
            },
            title: 'Usage for last 60 seconds',
            chart: {
                title: 'Water Usage',
                subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
            },
            legend: { position: "right" },
            curveType: 'function',
            colors: ['red'],
            height: 300,
        },
        granularity: 'day',
        waterRate: null,
        error: null,
        lastMinuteInSeconds: null,
        usageInDollars: null,
        rate: 2,
        value: null,
        enabled: true,
        colors:['yellow','darkyellow'],
    }
},
async mounted() {
    try{
        const response = await GetUsages.getLastMinuteInSeconds({
            username: this.$store.state.user.username,
            password: this.$store.state.user.password
        })
        let responseArray = response.data.mockWaterSeconds
        this.value = responseArray
        var startArrEntry = ['Seconds', 'Gallons Usage']
        var compArr = [startArrEntry].concat(this.value)
        this.chartData = compArr
        
    }
    catch(error){
        this.error = error.response.data.message
        console.log("mount fail")
    }
 },
created() {
    this.value = [1,2,3]
},
computed:{
    
},
methods: {
    async updateValue () {
        return [1,2,3]
    },
    async updateMinute () {
        const response = await GetUsages.getLastMinuteInSeconds({
            username: this.$store.state.user.username,
            password: this.$store.state.user.password
        })
        let responseArray = response.data.mockWaterSeconds
        this.value = responseArray
        var startArrEntry = ['Minutes', 'Gallons Usage']
        var compArr = [startArrEntry].concat(this.value)
        this.chartData = compArr
        this.chartOptions.hAxis.title = 'Seconds'
        this.chartOptions.title = 'Usage for the last 60 seconds'
    },
    async updateHour () {
        const response = await GetUsages.getLastHourInMinutes({
            username: this.$store.state.user.username,
            password: this.$store.state.user.password
        })
        let responseArray = response.data.mockWaterMinutes
        this.value = responseArray
        var startArrEntry = ['Minutes', 'Gallons Usage']
        var compArr = [startArrEntry].concat(this.value)
        this.chartData = compArr
        this.chartOptions.hAxis.title = 'Minutes'
        this.chartOptions.title = 'Usage for the last 60 minutes'
    },
    changePassword () {
    this.$router.push({
        name: 'newPassword'
        })
    }
   }
  }
</script>
```

And the code for the view where it should be displayed:

```
    <template>
    <div>
    <v-row>
        <v-col
        cols="12">
            <GChart
                type="LineChart"
                :data="chartData"
                :options="chartOptions"
                :colors="colors"
            />
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import GetUsages from '@/services/GetUsages'
    import GetService from '@/services/GetService'
    import { GChart } from 'vue-google-charts'

    export default {
       components: {
          GChart
       },
data () {
    return {
        print: null,
        selectedGradient: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
        chartData: null,
        chartOptions: {
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Seconds'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Gallons'
            },
            title: 'Usage for last 60 seconds',
            chart: {
                title: 'Water Usage',
                subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
            },
            legend: { position: "right" },
            curveType: 'function',
            colors: ['red'],
        },
        granularity: 'day',
        waterRate: null,
        error: null,
        lastMinuteInSeconds: null,
        usageInDollars: null,
        rate: 2,
        value: null,
        enabled: true,
        colors:['yellow','darkyellow'],
    }
},
async mounted() {
    try{
        const response = await GetUsages.getLastMinuteInSeconds({
            username: this.$store.state.user.username,
            password: this.$store.state.user.password
        })
        let responseArray = response.data.mockWaterSeconds
        this.value = responseArray
        var startArrEntry = ['Seconds', 'Gallons Usage']
        var compArr = [startArrEntry].concat(this.value)
        this.chartData = compArr
        
    }
    catch(error){
        this.error = error.response.data.message
        console.log("mount fail")
    }
 },
   created() {
    this.value = [1,2,3]
   },
   computed:{
    
},
methods: {
    async updateValue () {
        return [1,2,3]
    },
    async updateMinute () {
        const response = await GetUsages.getLastMinuteInSeconds({
            username: this.$store.state.user.username,
            password: this.$store.state.user.password
        })
        let responseArray = response.data.mockWaterSeconds
        this.value = responseArray
        var startArrEntry = ['Minutes', 'Gallons Usage']
        var compArr = [startArrEntry].concat(this.value)
        this.chartData = compArr
        this.chartOptions.hAxis.title = 'Seconds'
        this.chartOptions.title = 'Usage for the last 60 seconds'
    },
    async updateHour () {
        const response = await GetUsages.getLastHourInMinutes({
            username: this.$store.state.user.username,
            password: this.$store.state.user.password
        })
        let responseArray = response.data.mockWaterMinutes
        this.value = responseArray
        var startArrEntry = ['Minutes', 'Gallons Usage']
        var compArr = [startArrEntry].concat(this.value)
        this.chartData = compArr
        this.chartOptions.hAxis.title = 'Minutes'
        this.chartOptions.title = 'Usage for the last 60 minutes'
    },
    changePassword () {
    this.$router.push({
        name: 'newPassword'
        })
        }
      }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Sounds like your data isn't in the right format. You've shared a lot of code, but not mentioned which part the error happens in, can you put some breakpoints in and find out which dataset is causing the issue?

Comment: Both the client and server side are working in localhost, so it's something to do with either the graph itself or the data, but it was working correctly before I implemented the graph when I wanted to display the data normally in a v-container. I'll try and add the breakpoints and locate the data set that might be interfering.